# Recording Macros with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: macros, visual-studio

I am trying to use [Mouse Recorder Premium](http://mouserecorder.com/) to record a Macro in Visual Studio.

However, after I start recording the macro and switch to the Visual Studio window, none of the keystrokes are recorded in Visual Studio - it acts as if I am not doing anything.

This same behavior occurs when I try to record a macro with the software that came with my keyboard (Razor Blackwidow Ultimate).

What is going on?  Why can't anything see what Visual Studio is doing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it was because I was running Visual Studio as an admin but not the Macro recording program -